# Prepared statement saves '@name' and 0 values to the table

Tags: c#, mysql

I am building an application in C# that requires me to put data into a mySQL database. For that purpose, I am using prepared statements. A similar method with an update query works fine, however when I execute this function, the data is not properly inserted into the query, causing the database to contain the literal @username, @password values, and the rest of the columns contain 0's.

```
public static void Register(trinityRPG.World.Player player, string hashedPassword)
    {
        MySqlConnection db = Database.Core.getConnection();

        try
        {
            db.Open();

            string CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, `health`, `armour`, `skin`) VALUES (NULL, '@username', '@password', '@x', '@y', '@z', '@a', '@health', '@amour', '@skin');";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, db);
            cmd.Prepare();

            Console.WriteLine("Adding " + player.Name + " into the database");

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", player.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashedPassword);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", 71.1727);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", -100.62);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", 0.616854);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", 255.659);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@health", 100);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@armour", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skin", 2);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[DB driver] Error: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.Source);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of what the inserted row looks like:

```
id  username    password    x   y   z   a   health  armour  skin
8   @username   @password   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The ID is an int with the primary key, auto incremented. Username and password are strings. x, y, z, a, health and armour are floats and the skin is an int.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: MySQL is *implicitly converting* the *string* '@somethingthatisnotanumber' to 0 for the columns typed as integers. There is no such conversion for the char columns, which is why the '@parameternameinastring' shows up literally in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well*, you don't need to use single quotes for your parameters in your command. Just change your;

```
'@username'
```

to

```
@username
```

and for all other parameters. With `'@username'`, your command sees it as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), **not** a parameter.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to dispose your `MySqlConnection`  and `MySqlCommand` automaticly instead of calling `.Close()` method manually. And don't use `AddWithValue` method as much as you can. [It *may* generate upexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads to specify your parameter db type and it's size.

```
using(MySqlConnection db= new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, `health`, `armour`, `skin`) 
                         VALUES (NULL, @username, @password, @x, @y, @z, @a, @health, @amour, @skin)";

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", player.Name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashedPassword);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", 71.1727);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", -100.62);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", 0.616854);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", 255.659);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@health", 100);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@armour", 0);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skin", 2);

     db.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) well said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406499/prepared-statement-saves-name-and-0-values-to-the-table#comment46987680_29406499) by the way.

> MySQL is implicitly converting the string '@somethingthatisnotanumber'
>   to 0 for the columns typed as integers. There is no such conversion
>   for the char columns, which is why the '@parameternameinastring' shows
>   up literally in them

Comment: When i change that, the following exception occurs during the execution of the query: [DB driver] Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution.  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at trinityRPG.Database.Player.Register (trinityRPG.World.Player player, System.String hashedPassword) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: @FlorianVanDillen I don't see any `ExecuteReader` in your code. On which line throws this exception?

Comment: @FlorianVanDillen I also added as an example code. Can you please try it? Since you didn't tell your column types, I have to use `AddWithValue` in my example.

Comment: Your example code worked flawlessly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement has string literal quotes around the parameter names in the VALUES section:

```
VALUES (NULL, '@username', '@password', '@x', '@y', '@z', '@a', '@health', '@amour', '@skin');
```

This is instructing MySQL to insert the string literal '@username' for the Username parameter. Simply remove the quotes:

```
VALUES (NULL, @username, @password, @x, @y, @z, @a, @health, @amour, @skin);
```